# Regex to Match if a string is not sandwiched between two tokens

Tags: regex, string, perl, regex-lookarounds

I'm having trouble with a regex I'm working on. Essentially, I want to match a string iff there is not a particular string between the beginning and end. Let me clarify, with an excluded string (123), a beginning (hello), and an end (abc):

```
hello123abc   ==> no match
helloa123abc  ==> no match
hello123aabc  ==> no match
helloa123aabc ==> no match
hello1abc     ==> match
hello23abc    ==> match
helloaabc     ==> match
helloabc      ==> match
```

I have a skeleton framework:

```
=~ m/hello___abc
```

and have tried filling in the blank with all of the following:

```
(?!123).*?
.*?(?!123)
.*?(?!123).*?
(?!123)
(?!123)*?
.*?[^1][^2][^3].*?
```

and a few other combinations that I can't remember, but none of them has worked. Does anyone have a way to do this?

Comment: Does the whole string begin with "hello" and end with "abc" or is it a part of a larger string?

Comment: Use a look ahead and look behind...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you could use the PCRE verbs `(*SKIP)(*F)`,

```
(?:hello.*?123.*?abc)(*SKIP)(*F)|hello.*?abc
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dR4bN1/4)

**OR**

```
(?:hello(?:(?!hello).)*123.*?abc)(*SKIP)(*F)|hello.*?abc
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dR4bN1/6)

Comment: Thanks, best response by far.

Comment: @perlmonkwannabe Except it doesn't actually work.  If a line contains a false string after a good one, neither will match.  [As demoed](http://regex101.com/r/dR4bN1/5)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're making this too hard.

Instead of focusing on what you want to match (which is unclear), just focus on what you don't and then invert the logic.

Assuming line by line processing, the following would work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (! /hello.*123.*abc/) {
        print "matches  - $_";
    } else {
        print "no match - $_";
    }
}

__DATA__
hello123abc
helloa123abc
hello123aabc
helloa123aabc
hello1abc
hello23abc
helloaabc
helloabc
```

Outputs:

```
no match - hello123abc
no match - helloa123abc
no match - hello123aabc
no match - helloa123aabc
matches  - hello1abc
matches  - hello23abc
matches  - helloaabc
matches  - helloabc
```

#### Extrapolated answer for capturing instead of just matching

If you're wanting to not just match, but to capture strings that are bounded by hello and abc but do not contain 123, then the following would work for you:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = do {local $/; <DATA>};

while ($data =~ m/(hello(?:(?!123).)*?abc)/g) {
    print "matches - $1\n";
}

__DATA__
hello123abc hello1abc helloa123abchello123aabc
hello23abc helloaabc helloa123aabc helloabc
```

Outputs:

```
matches - hello1abc
matches - hello23abc
matches - helloaabc
matches - helloabc
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to describe only allowed characters between the two strings *("hello" and "abc")*. to do that you need to exclude the first character of the string you want to forbid, and the first character of the end substring to describe allowed characters between substrings:

```
^hello(?>[^1a]+|1(?!23)|a(?!bc$))*abc$
```

To do the same in a larger string *(that contains several "hello"..."abc" parts)*, you only need to remove the anchors:

```
hello(?>[^1a]+|1(?!23)|a(?!bc))*abc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   (?!^hello.*?123)(^.*$)
```

This will work.

See Demo..

http://regex101.com/r/uU0hL0/1